# Need to create a script that scans for file names, generates a template for each file and inserts filename into 2 spots within template

Tags: powershell

Basically what I need is a way to scan a folder for certain files (let's say anything with .xls/xlsx) and generate a text file for each one of those files with a template layout. I figured out how to do this with the script below. However, I need it also to place the filename within the template file as well in 2 locations.

Here is how I have it now.

```
Get-ChildItem "*PATH*" | Foreach-Object {$_.Name} > C:\Temp\TextGenerate\FileNames.txt 

Get-Content C:\Temp\TextGenerate\FileNames.txt | ForEach-Object {
  Copy-Item -Path C:\Temp\TextGenerate\FileTemplate.txt -Destination ("C:\Temp\TextGenerate\ListFiles\{0}.txt" -f $_)
}
```

Basically it scans the folder location, creates a text file (FileNames.txt) with all the file names using a file template file (FileTemplate.txt) and creates one for each file name.

This template (FileTemplate.txt) would be like this:

```
REPORT-ID=TEST FILE=\\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXX\*insert filename here*, TYPE=XLSX, "SECTION=TEST" TOPIC-ID=TOPIC1, "TOPIC-ITEM=*insert filename here*"
```

Output would need to be:

```
REPORT-ID=TEST FILE=\\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXX\filename1.xlsx, TYPE=XLSX, "SECTION=TEST" TOPIC-ID=TOPIC1, "TOPIC-ITEM=filename1.xlsx"
```

and so on.

Everything on the template would always be the same the only thing that would need to change for each file generated would be the filename for each file found in the folder in the `*insert filename here*` location.

I am having a problem understand how to insert such things into the file. I would also like if possible to insert the data modified into another line of text in the generated template if possible.

Comment: Read template file `$templ=Get-Content  -Path 'C:\Temp\TextGenerate\FileTemplate.txt'` and then `… | ForEach-Object {$templ.Replace('*insert filename here*',$_) | Set-Content -Path ("C:\Temp\TextGenerate\ListFiles\{0}.txt" -f $_)}` or something alike?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JosefZ [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666852/need-to-create-a-script-that-scans-for-file-names-generates-a-template-for-each#comment74387715_43666852): read the template file just once, then create the files by filling the template string with values and writing the modified string to the output files.

I would, however, recommend modifying the template to allow using the format operator (`-f`) on it:

```
REPORT-ID=TEST FILE=\\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXX\{0}, TYPE=XLSX, "SECTION=TEST" TOPIC-ID=TOPIC1, "TOPIC-ITEM={0}"
```

Also, there's no need to write the names to a file first. Change your code to something like this:

```
$template = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\TextGenerate\FileTemplate.txt' | Out-String

Get-ChildItem "*PATH*" | Select-Object -Expand Name | ForEach-Object {
  $path    = "C:\Temp\TextGenerate\ListFiles\{0}.txt" -f $_
  $content = $template -f $_
  Set-Content -Path $path -Value $content
}
```

Comment: This was perfect thank you. The only issue it seems to have is when it creates the file from the template it doesn't keep the format. It seems to put it on one line. It will need to retain the format of the original template (3 lines).

Comment: Never mind, figured out the formating. I just used a delimiter for get content!

Comment: So I guess my next question if it isn't considered taking advantage of you guys is, is there a way to read the last modified date and inject it into another line in the template. it would need to be in the YYYYMMDD

Comment: Your template example didn't look like it had multiple lines. If it does: use `Get-Content -Raw` (PowerShell v3 or newer) or pipe the `Get-Content` output through `Out-String`. As for your followup question: of course it's possible. Please do some research on the format operator and reading file attributes. If you still can't get it to work afterwards: post a new question.